# Unsupported operand types after PDO conversion

Tags: php, pdo, operands

This line of code has begun producing an error since I've begun converting my code to PDO:

`$colcount = floor(($total / $columns) + ($total % $columns ? 1 : 0));`

The error it returns is:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

I have searched for this issue but can't seem to find an answer to apply to my specific code.

If anyone could point me to an answer or give an explanation or example of what's causing this and how it can be repaired, I'd be very grateful.

I can also post the surrounding code, if it helps.

Comment: There is nothing PDO in that line of code.

Comment: Correct, but once I converted the code before it to PDO, it started producing an error when it didn't originally.

Comment: Sans any other code we cannot tell how PDO would affect this line of code.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you attempt to use arithmetic operators on an array instead of proper numeric value(s).  `$total` and/or `$columns` is an array.  `var_dump()` them to see.

Comment: I see now. Thank you. `$total` is an array. Since you know much more about this than I could probably figure out, what kind of fix would you recommend here? Either way, thank you for the well worded response.

Comment: Post a new question showing the code you use to get `$total` and `$columns` and do a `var_dump()` of them.  This will be basic troubleshooting.